# Where do I put a addValueEventListener that only gets triggered when there's a change in my Firebase Realtime Database for my fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, moshi

In my `Fragment` for my Android app, I'm using Firebase Realtime Database and `Moshi` to save and load the data I get from my `RecyclerView`.

These are the functions I use for this task:

```
private fun saveData() {
    val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(BigDecimalAdapter).add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()
    val listMyData = Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, ItemCard::class.java)
    val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<ArrayList<ItemCard>> = moshi.adapter(listMyData)
    val json = jsonAdapter.toJson(dataList)
    userInfo.child("jsonData").setValue(json)
}

private fun loadData(json: String) = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    if (json != "") {
        val type: Type = object : TypeToken<List<ItemCard>>() {}.type
        val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(BigDecimalAdapter).add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()
        val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<ArrayList<ItemCard>> = moshi.adapter(type)
        dataList = jsonAdapter.fromJson(json)!!
        if (dataList == null) {
            dataList = arrayListOf<ItemCard>()
        }
    }
}

private fun buildRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_recycler_view)
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerViewLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@Main.requireContext())
    adapter = MainAdapter(dataList, this)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = recyclerViewLayoutManager
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
}
```

In my `onViewCreated`, I having this for loading the data and building the `RecyclerView`:

```
userInfo.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (postSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
            when (postSnapshot.key) {
                "jsonData" -> {
                    loadData(postSnapshot.value.toString())
                    buildRecyclerView()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
})
```

Everything works as I want, however, there's a delay/lag when I go to this specific fragment. There are a total of three fragments in my app. The other two work smoothly with no delay/lag, but when I click on the button or slide the screen to go to this fragment, there's a delay in the change of the UI.

What can I do to make the performance better? Where should I put my `addValueEventListener`? I only want it to get triggered when the fragment is first created and when the `jsonData` child gets changed. I believe in my `onViewCreated` the listener is being triggered multiple times. Is there anything else I can add to my code or modify to make the performance better when saving and loading the RecyclerView data?

Comment: If there is a delay in this code, but not in the other places where you use the same approach, the most likely difference is in the amount of data you load. How does that compare between the three places you mention?

Comment: In my other fragment that's also loading data from Firebase Realtime Database, it's loading strings that are between 1-7 characters. The length for the `jsonData` string is 4903.

Comment: What is the amount of data you are loading? Have many objects are returned by your queries?

Comment: @AlexMamo For each row item in the `RecyclerView`, it stores a `data class` that has three string values and one `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 0):

when you create a listerner in onViewCreated run then make sure that you remove listener when fragment is not attach.Realtime event listerner return a string that you can easily = to your pojo class like:

```
ItemCard message = messageSnapshot.getValue(ItemCard.class);
```

this way is to saving manual converting the list effort.Last important thing that if recyclerview is initialize then don't initialize when data change only notifyDataSetChange.when you adding data in the list then make sure that the

```
list.clear();
```

otherwise you data is duplicate because on addValueEventListener return the whole data.